# Node unit test - mocking calls to solr

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, solr, nodeunit

For my application i have used solr-node client
    How can i write unit tests by mocking the calls to the solr module?
    Can someone pls help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JsMockito](http://jsmockito.org/) - it's a JavaScript based mocking framework that allows you to mock up objects, function calls, and returns in your project.